# Why does Dev C++ stop working before running the whole code in finding highest and lowest number between 10 elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, max, min

This is the code that I made to find the highest and lowest number between 10 elements:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 10
void acceptNumbers (int Numbers[SIZE]);
int High(int Numbers[SIZE]);
int Low(int Numbers[SIZE]);

void acceptNumbers(int Numbers[SIZE])
{int i, *max, *min;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    cin>>Numbers[i];

    max = Numbers;
    min = Numbers;
}

int High(int Numbers[SIZE])
{int i, *max;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (*(Numbers+i) > *max)
            max = (Numbers+i);
    }
    cout<<*max;
}

int Low(int Numbers[SIZE])
{int i, *min;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (*(Numbers+i) < *min)
        min = (Numbers+i);
    }
    cout<<*min;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[SIZE];

    cout<<"Enter Elements: \n";
    acceptNumbers(arr);

    cout<<"Highest Number: ";
    High(arr);
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Lowest Number: ";
    Low(arr);
    cout<<endl;
    }
```

On my PC, it doesn't run the whole program. It just stops right when it reaches the code for finding the highest and lowest number
[image]

This is homework I'm working on and I can't use any shortcuts and whatnots since there is a required line of code to be used that is given. And so I tried running this code on another PC and it worked just fine:

[image]

I also tried running it on online c++ compiler and it still doesn't work. I can't find solution online so this is my last resort please help me

Comment: shouldn't you define ```max``` in ```High()``` to a value first?   You haven't defined what's ```max```.  Ditto with ```min``` in ```Low()```.

Comment: `int i, *max;` -- `max` is an uninitialized pointer, and you never point it to anywhere valid here: `if (*(Numbers+i) > *max)`.  This has nothing to do with any of the compilers -- the faults are the bugs in your code.

Comment: *And so I tried running this code on another PC and it worked just fine:* -- When you dereference an uninitialized pointer, the behavior of the code is undefined.  It's similar to using a rope that can only hold 500 pounds, but you attempt to hold 600 pounds and the rope doesn't break.  Maybe it will break later, maybe it will never break, you don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your code exhibits **undefined behavior**.

In each of your functions, you are declaring `min` and `max` as local variables. Thus, when you initialize `min`/`max` in `acceptNumbers()`, they are only initialized in that function.  You are not initializing the `min`/`max` variables in `High()`/`Low()` at all. Your code is crashing when those functions try to dereference those uninitialized variables.

Also, your `High()`/`Low()` functions have non-`void` return types, but are not actually `return`'ing any values.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 10
void acceptNumbers (int Numbers[SIZE]);
int High(int Numbers[SIZE]);
int Low(int Numbers[SIZE]);

void acceptNumbers(int Numbers[SIZE])
{
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        cin>>Numbers[i];
}

int High(int Numbers[SIZE])
{
    int *max = Numbers;
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (*(Numbers+i) > *max)
            max = (Numbers+i);
    }
    return *max;
}

int Low(int Numbers[SIZE])
{
    int *min = Numbers;
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (*(Numbers+i) < *min)
            min = (Numbers+i);
    }
    return *min;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[SIZE];

    cout<<"Enter Elements: \n";
    acceptNumbers(arr);

    cout<<"Highest Number: ";
    cout<<High(arr);
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Lowest Number: ";
    cout<<Low(arr);
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions Low() and High() only declare the int* max, min but never initialize. Though they hold invalid addresses.

```
if (*(Numbers + i) > *max)
```

This function causes a segmentation fault because your program tries to dereference an invalid memory address.

If you want to store `int *min, *max` make them either global or declare them in main().